# how get ssh awk remote values

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, ssh

im using this script

```
[test@sys-master ~]$ parallel -k -j 100 sshpass -p test1213'!' ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no -q root@10.0.{}  "cat /proc/loadavg | awk -F \" \"  '{ print   a,\$1,b }' a="'"$(hostname)"'" b=\$(nproc)" ::: {41..46}.{1..100}
```

why return back local value?
i need remote(node) values

```
 sys-master 9.87 24
    sys-master 9.99 24
    sys-master 11.85 24
    sys-master 11.67 24
    sys-master 10.75 24
    sys-master 8.00 24
    sys-master 10.27 24
    sys-master 11.94 24
    sys-master 10.28 24
    sys-master 10.94 24
    sys-master 12.02 24
    sys-master 9.55 24
    sys-master 11.43 2
```

Comment: You only need the `cat` on the remote server, the rest can be done locally. Things like this are also easily done using Ansible. Also, you have a typo (a missing backslash in front of `$(hostname)`).

Comment: `parallel -k -j 100 sshpass -p test1213\! ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no -q 
        root@10.0.{} "</proc/loadavg awk -v hostName='$(hostname)' -v nProc='$(nproc)' '{ print hostName, \$1, nProc }'" ::: {41..46}.{1..100}`, I'm not posting this as an answer since I'm not sure it there is any other issues with `parallel` commnad syntax (because I never used it).

Comment: `cat /proc/loadavg | awk 'foo'` = `awk 'foo' /proc/loadavg`. See https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to quoting.

GNU Parallel is not part of the shell so every input has to be quoted if it would be interpreted by the shell. And since you call GNU Parallel from a shell (which will interpret input) and GNU Parallel starts a shell (that interprets the input) it has to be quoted twice, unless you use `-q`, which you can only use if you need the full line to be quoted (i.e. no composed command).

As you can tell it very quickly get confusing. :)

So the general recommendation is to define a bash function and call that.

```
myloadavg() {
  sshpass -p test1213'!' ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no -q root@10.0.$1  "cat /proc/loadavg | awk -F \" \"  '{ print   a,\$1,b }' a="'"\$(hostname)"'" b=\$(nproc)"
}
export -f myloadavg
parallel myloadavg ::: {41..46}.{1..100}
```

Comment: You also evaluate `$(hostname)` locally, which was what the actual question was about.